# Multiple services from single exe

Tags: .net

I have created two services from single exe deployed as windows services. Each service corresponds to a dll(class library project). When I stop the service, the dll does not unload and the code that corresponds to this dll continue to run. I have a poller that runs periodically and this continues to poll even when service is shut down. How can I unload the corresponding dll when the service stops?

Answer (score 0):

unloading a dll is not the dot-net way of doing things. you should rather override the onStop() method of the service class. set some flag which signals the corresponding dlls to refrain from answering to polls. you may kill the poller thread or better still use semaphore to block the thread until started/resumed.

if you show some code then we can help further. guessing,

is there a timer which triggers the poll process? then stop/dispose that timer. create a fresh timer in OnStart() of the service. another way is to check the flag in timer's callback.

is there an infinite while loop which does the polling (again and again)? if there is one then better refactor the code to use a timer instead. anyway you can insert a flag in the body of the loop and continue loop if the flag is set.